# return self before async request finished

Tags: objective-c, image, asynchronous, request, afnetworking

Hey im having this code so far

```
- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)aDictionary {
    self = [super init];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    _userAvatar = [self getUserAvatar:[aDictionary objectForKey:@"user_avatar"]];
    _userId = [aDictionary objectForKey:@"user_id"];
    _username = [aDictionary objectForKey:@"username"];
    _userEmail = [aDictionary objectForKey:@"user_email"];
    return self;
}


- (UIImage *)getUserAvatar:(NSString *)avatarPath {

    __block UIImage *avatarImage = [[UIImage alloc]init];
    if ([avatarPath length] != 0) {
        [[AFFnBAPIClient sharedClient] setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"image/png"];
        [[AFFnBAPIClient sharedClient] getPath:FNB_DOWNLOAD_PATH parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:avatarPath forKey:@"avatar"] success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id image) {
            avatarImage = image;
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error");
        }];
    } else {
        UIImage *placeholderImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];
        avatarImage = placeholderImage;
    }
    return avatarImage;
}
```

my problem is return self is called before the async request is finished, how do i return self with the request finished without a synchronous request?

Comment: If you don't want it to return until the request is finished, isn't that the definition of a synchronous request? Your question seems to be "how do I block without blocking?" Or do you mean "how do I get make AFFnBAPIClient into a synchronous request?"

Comment: so i guess its not possible to return self without a synchronous request in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do it like this:

```
- (id)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)aDictionary {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        // for starters, it's a placeholder
        self.userAvatar = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"];

        // now go get the avatar, fill it in whenever the get finishes.
        // notice there's no return value.
        [self getUserAvatar:[aDictionary objectForKey:@"user_avatar"]];

        // make sure these are retained (or strong in ARC) properties.
        // your code looked like it was releasing these
        self.userId = [aDictionary objectForKey:@"user_id"];
        self.username = [aDictionary objectForKey:@"username"];
        self.userEmail = [aDictionary objectForKey:@"user_email"];
    }
    return self;
}

// see - no return value.  it's asynch
- (void)getUserAvatar:(NSString *)avatarPath {

    // don't need a __block var here
    if ([avatarPath length] != 0) {
        [[AFFnBAPIClient sharedClient] setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"image/png"];
        [[AFFnBAPIClient sharedClient] getPath:FNB_DOWNLOAD_PATH parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:avatarPath forKey:@"avatar"] success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id image) {

            // self got a retain+1 while this was running.
            self.userAvatar = image;

        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Error");
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: the main problem is I'm calling this

`User *user = [[User alloc] initWithDictionary:forUser];
    [userDic setObject:user forKey:@"user"];`

so userDic has already the user object before the user object gets its avatarImage

Comment: That has to happen.  The avatar will show up sometime after.  The code I supplied will update userAvatar when the image arrives.  Maybe you're having trouble updating the UI after that happens?  For now, put a breakpoint on the line in the block self.userAvatar = image;  Inspect to see that you have a good self and a good image.

Comment: the image gets set but after I'm passing userDic to another Controller, so i can never access the real image via `[[userDic objectForKey@"user"] userAvatar]` because its already set to the placeholder image, i guess it's a little complicated ;). This whole code above is inside a class User.m and it gets initialized with the code in my above comment and gets passed to its delegate method `[self.delegate loadUserData:userDic];`

Comment: @daiikota, sorry, it's too hard to understand without the code.  Maybe you could check this answer off and open a new question with the relevant code?  The methods here will init that object, set a placeholder for userAvatar and return it.  Sometime later, it will set the avatar to a fetched image (over-writing the placeholder).  Wherever that object goes, inside of other dictionaries or wherever, it should have either a placeholder or the fetched image once it arrives.  Your UI might need to realize that the image changed and update itself, but that's a different problem/question.

Comment: it finally works with adding an observer to the new controller and observing the image :)